# SQL AVG() function returning incorrect values

Tags: sql, average

I want to use the AVG function in sql to return a working average for some values (ie based on the last week not an overall average).  I have two values I am calculating, *weight* and *restingHR* (heart rate).  I have the following sql statements for each:

```
SELECT AVG( weight ) AS average 
FROM   stats 
WHERE  userid='$userid' 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 7

SELECT AVG( restingHR ) AS average 
FROM   stats 
WHERE  userid='$userid' 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 7
```

The value I get for *weight* is **82.56** but it should be **83.35**
This is not a massive error and I'm rounding it when I use it so its not too big a deal.

However for *restingHR* I get **45.96** when it should be **57.57** which is a massive difference.

I don't understand why this is going so wrong.  Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How do you know the value should be **83.35**? Please can you post the data you are using?

Comment: Are you certain the column used does not contain `NULL` values?

Comment: What do you mean by `order by` and `limit` here, anyway?

Comment: Paster the result of this query and let's see your data `SELECT weight AS average 
FROM   stats 
WHERE  userid='$userid' 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 7`

Comment: You could try filtering with between instead of using order by: WHERE userid='$userid' and date BETWEEN '01/11/2012' and '09/11/2012'...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a subquery to separate selecting the rows from computing the average:

```
SELECT AVG(weight) average
FROM (SELECT weight
      FROM stats
      WHERE userid = '$userid'
      ORDER BY date DESC
      LIMIT 7) subq
```

Comment: +1 : Just to add to this answer, because it doesn't explicitly state why this is necessary: `LIMIT 7` restricts how many rows can be output. When you are aggregating, the number of records supplied to the aggregate is not affected at all. For example `SELECT x, AVG(y) FROM z GROUP BY x ORDER BY x LIMIT 7` will return result for 7 different values of `x`, but each row could be the aggregate of a million rows each. In your case you want to limit the number of rows being aggregated. By using a sub query you are able to use `LIMIT` to select only 7 rows, then use the outer query to aggregate.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. 
I need to increase my SQL knowledge but have only learnt stuff that I have needed.  Mostly simple stuff until now.

Comment: The important thing to remember is that LIMIT and ORDER BY operate on the results, as tombom said. The way you wrote it, it meant "return at most 7 rows of averages", not "return the average of at most 7 rows".

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to filter your data with `ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 7`, but you have to consider, that the `ORDER BY` clause takes effect **after** everything else is done. So your `AVG()` function considers all values of restingHR from your `$userId`, not just the 7 latest.

To overcome this...okay, Barmar just posted a query.